# Journey Builder deduplication

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

When you are in email studio and send an email you have the possibility to deduplicate subscribers based on their email address in the sending dataextension(s).

In Journey builder you do not have that possibility when sending emails to subscribers when you do not use the email address as the subscriberkey but something like a customer number.

How can you deduplicate in this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

There is not out of the box feature to deduplicate email addresses in journey builder if the email address is not your subscriber key. The easiest way to do this is to filter out the rows with duplicate email addresses before you insert the records into your journey entry source DE.

Here's a sample query to deduplicate email addresses using partition by,

```
SELECT  SubscriberKey, EmailAddress, Date_added, Row FROM
(SELECT SubscriberKey, EmailAddress, Date_added, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EmailAddress ORDER BY DATE_ADDED DESC) 
        AS Row
 FROM [SOURCEDE]) as s
 WHERE row=1
```

Data action: Update

Target DE: Journey Entry Source DE

Comment: Careful there, even if Email is subscriberkey 2 emails are sent by the journey, I just tested that. You have to dedup via query as you say.

Comment: @Johhnytska it depends on the journey settings then. in that case you should not allow re-entry.

Comment: That's another way of controlling, I always prefer to do it with SQL